# svg: change fill color using css

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this svg file which I want to use with different colors

I have tried the following

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" width="100" height="100" data="todo.svg">
    <span/>
</object>
```

(Not sure if OBJECT is the correct element for this)

Here is the content of **todo.svg**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="..." x="0px" y="0px"
     width="156px" height="141.6px" viewBox="0 0 156 141.6" enable-background="new 0 0 156 141.6" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        ....
        <g id="bar">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#000" d="..."/>

        </g>
    </g>
    ....
```

So in the css I tried to style this as follows

```
#bar path { fill: #444; }
```

Doesn't work :( Any suggestions how I can change this svg property using css ?

Comment: the css of your page cannot access external content include in a frame or an object. What you can do is to use include() in php (if avalaible on your server) or include the svg code within your html instead of object here an example of svg inside document and receiving style , (used for another question here ) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Dqcio

Comment: would you not give the path a class and then style the class with something like `.className {fill: #444;}` - [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc3ds/5/) where the colour of the item is changed on hover

Comment: @Pete if svg is in object, no way to style it from main page :) just like if you show google in it , you cannot restyle it via css from your site see your fiddle and svg in object http://jsfiddle.net/Qc3ds/6/